# TSQL Date conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have a table of events, constantly being updated, with a datetime column.

I want to get all events that start today as well as the ones that start 8 hours into the next day.

The idea is that people don't really check in the middle of the night for events, so we list them in the day before.

To get today's I do `DATEDIFF(day,eventdate,GETDATE())=0` but I havn't figured out how to do `the dateadd()` for my case. I either get no rows or too many.

So the wanted result is:

`From 00:00 on March 9 to 8:00 on March 10.` (example only)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better to **not** do any calculation on your column. Calculate the interval instead and fetch the rows that is in the interval. That way you can make use of a index on `eventdate` instead of doing a table scan.

```
select SomeColumns
from YourTable
where eventdate >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0) and
      eventdate < dateadd(hour, 32, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these to bound your query...

```
DECLARE @Start DateTime = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GetDate(), 121)
DECLARE @End DateTime = DATEADD(Hour, +32, @Start)
```

Here's a Test Script

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (Column1 DateTime)

INSERT INTO #Temp (column1) values (getdate()) -- it's 6pm now
INSERT INTO #Temp (column1) values (dateadd(hour, -24, getdate())) --6pm yesterday - outside window
INSERT INTO #Temp (column1) values (dateadd(hour, -12, getdate())) --6am today
INSERT INTO #Temp (column1) values (dateadd(hour, -5, getdate())) -- 1pm today
INSERT INTO #Temp (column1) values (dateadd(hour, +12, getdate())) -- 6am tomorrow - inside window
INSERT INTO #Temp (column1) values (dateadd(hour, +17, getdate())) -- 11am tomorrow - outside window

select * from #Temp

DECLARE @Start DateTime = CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GetDate(), 121)
DECLARE @End DateTime = DateAdd(Hour, +32, @Start)

SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE Column1 > @Start AND Column1 < @End
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Column1, Column2
FROM
    TableName
WHERE
    DateColumm BETWEEN Convert(Date, GETDATE()) AND DateAdd(hh, 32, Convert(smalldatetime, Convert(Date, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
select *
from yourtable
WHERE EventDate >= Convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)
AND EventDate < CAST(Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, 1, getdate()), 101) +  ' 08:00 AM' as datetime)
```

Then if you EventDate has the time on it, then you can convert the EventDate in the first part of your `WHERE` clause

```
select *
from yourtable
WHERE Convert(varchar(10), EventDate, 101) >= Convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101)
AND EventDate < CAST(Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, 1, getdate()), 101) +  ' 08:00 AM' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

The [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) documention page shows all the different date parts you can use (hour, day, seconds, etc.)

```
DECLARE @StartTimeWindow DATETIME, @EndTimeWindow DATETIME
SET @StartTimeWindow = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())
SET @EndTimeWindow = DATEADD(HOUR, 32, @StartTimeWindow)

SELECT *
FROM EventTable
WHERE EventDate >= @StartTimeWindow
  AND EventDate <= @EndTimeWindow
```